# TextView not centred in Android

Tags: android, textview

For some reason my text view is being left aligned instead of appearing in the centre of the page.

Here is the code I am using; can anyone see anything wrong with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/break_option"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Pass/fail buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">    

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/custom_pass"
                        style="@style/Custom_Button_Yes"
                        android:layout_width="100dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/pass" />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/custom_fail"
                        style="@style/Custom_Button_No"
                        android:layout_width="100dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fail" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is an image of what it appears like in my mobile:

[image: http://s13.postimg.org/op2meq0fr/ss1.png]

How can I get it horizontally centre aligned?

---

Edit: thank you all for your help. arthur_gg was the first one I saw so I will mark his as correct but I have given you all votes. Thanks again

Comment: `TextView` is center aligned but text length is more then one line so new line added you can check it by minimizing text length like "Press fail" or by adjusting font size of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use TextView's `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center"`

Just replace your TextView xml code with below one:

```
<TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/break_option"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

and you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TextView
         style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press fail it is break"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

**Graphical layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try Relative layout instead of Linearlayout. it helped  me if you dont want to change it then use `android:gravity="center"` in your TextView

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
  style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:text="@string/break_option" />`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and is working fine. I have just changed the string to simple quotes.

```
    <TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Press fail if this is a break" />

    <!-- Pass/fail buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_pass"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pass" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_fail"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fail" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```